# Why does memory consumption in python do not return to as it was when file is read and data is no longer being used

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a code that reads a file, and then immediately deletes the read data. However the memory consumption of process before reading the data and after the data has been read and deleted do not match.

```
import psutil
import os
import json
import gc
def main():
    pid = os.getpid()
    print(f"pid of program is {pid}")

    memory_info = psutil.Process(pid).memory_info()
    print(f'current memory consumption is {memory_info.rss / (1024 * 1024)} MB')


    with open('temp.json', 'r') as file: # some large file of some 5.6 MB
        c = file.read()
        data = json.loads(c)
    memory_info = psutil.Process(pid).memory_info()
    print(f'memory consumption after reading is {memory_info.rss / (1024 * 1024)} MB')


    del data
    gc.collect()
    memory_info = psutil.Process(pid).memory_info()
    print(f'memory consumption after deleting is {memory_info.rss / (1024 * 1024)} MB')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output

```
pid of program is 7953
current memory consumption is 11.875 MB
memory consumption after reading is 35.0859375 MB
memory consumption after deleting is 25.3515625 MB
```

While I do understand that memory before reading the file and after reading will be significantly different, and even after deleting the data doesn't have to be exactly same as before but shouldn't consumption be close to what it was before after deleting data ?

**If not wouldn't an API that serves large quantity of unique response always keep increasing memory consumption ??**

Comment: Just an FYI, `gc` likely doesn't have much bearing here. `gc` is for collecting circular references only. Most data is freed via reference counting, and you have little control over that. `del` doesn't delete the data, it deletes the reference, which decrements the reference counter, which *may* result in the data being freed if that was the last reference.

Comment: And how big is the file? That 25mb/35mb might contain other stuff just related to the execution of the program.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, file in this very specific case is of 5.6MB containing json data.

Comment: Well, memory consumption raised by more than that after reading the file, and dropped more than that after potentially allowing reference counting to free the data. I don't see a problem here. I'm guessing the residual memory usage is just related to the interpreter allocating resources..

Comment: Agreed, that brings to my second question. Assume there is an API that does fairly same thing as the program is doing, however with each consecutive request a new file is read and returned. **Wouldn't it always keep increasing the memory usage ?** on every call ?

Comment: No. If the increase in memory is due to the interpreter doing something like caching resources or simply lazily loading resources, you could expect an initial usage of memory, but then, over time, you should expect memory usage to remain stable. Resources should be allocated, used, then deallocated, and this happens on every request,

Comment: the main point, as mentioned my @Carcigenicate is that python manages memmory by reference counting. So when the reference is removed (drops to zero) then the memory is released.